# Java class not found in a directory hierarchy

Tags: java

I am getting the following error when running a java program:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Gen
```

I have the following directory structure:

- The curent directory from where I run the program contains the directories hierarchy: 
  classes/gensig/gen and classes/gensig/util. In this directories I have the classes I need.
- I want to run the class Gen from classes/gensig/gen. in classes/gensig/util I have some classes I call in Gen class.
- I run the program like this but I get the error I mentioned:

`java -cp classes/gensig/gen/*.class:classes/gensig/util/*.class Gen`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the package name for `Gen` class?

Comment: The packege name is gen for gen class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classpath must contain directories or jar files which constitute the root of a package tree (i.e. a directory which constitutes the default package, and which contains the directories of top-level packages).

In your cases, it looks like the class is called `Gen`, and is in the package `gensig.gensig`. Its name is thus `gensig.gensig.Gen`. The root of the package tree is the directory `classes`. So the command should be:

```
java -cp classes gensig.gensig.Gen
```

EDIT: given your comment, your classes are actually in the package `gen`. The root of the package tree is thus `classes/gensig`. So the command should be

```
java -cp classes/gensig gen.Gen
```

Comment: I am getting this error when I use the command above Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gensig/gen/Gen (wrong name: gen/Gen). Also I need to include the classes from util. How can I do that.

Comment: The classes from `util` are included, since the root of the package/directory tree (`classes`) is in the classpath. `CorviGen` can't be found since it's in the package `gensig.gen`, and you don't have any corresponding directory under classes. Do you understand that the package tree must match with the directory tree? If you're stuck, post the code of all your classes (from the package statement to the declaration of the class), and tell us the command you use to compile them.

Comment: I have this class Gen, I edited. I used the command you say 'java -cp classes gensig.gen.Gen' but I am still getting the error 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gensig/gen/Gen (wrong name: gen/Gen)'

Comment: Did you read my answer? The command is `java -cp classes gensig.gensig.Gen`. Not `java -cp classes gensig.gen.Gen`. You must pass the fully qualified name of the class. It's as simple as that. And the fully quelified name is the package of the class, followed by a dot, followed by the simple name of the class. And the package structure must match exactly with the directory structure. Without more info about your code, we can't help.

Comment: It worked like this java -cp classes/gensig gen.Gen. In the classes directory beside gensig I had other directories containing classes and using -cp classes/gensig worked for me. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Ok, i used gensig.gen.Gen because this is the structure of directory classes/gensig/gen/, I edited later from classes/gensig/gensig/.

Comment: You should really read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html